# comparing satisfaction rankings over time

Tags: regression, survey

looking for some analytics inspiration.

If I have a list of satisfaction rankings (0 to 100) for one year. In future years I will recollect the data.

What are some nice ways to present the data now and that suitable for trend analysis in future years?

So far I've looked at the mean, percentage < 50 and > 50, box a whisker plot.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to CV! Your current question is too broad to answer succinctly. There are numerous ways you could potentially summarize your data. If you have a specific question, please edit your post with the button below it.

Comment: @FransRodenburg The question is broad, but there are still ways to provide some useful guidelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the amount of data you have and how "precise" it is (i.e. what the real difference between, let's say, 70 and 71 actually is, or is the difference between 60 and 70 really the same as between 70 and 80)

But assuming a decent number of satisfaction evaluations, apart from those you mentioned, I would consider a histogram (using the number of breaks that better suits your particular case) With that, you can have a grasp, on a single plot, of your sample distribution.

You may also want to try a "cummulative version" of that histogram, by plotting, for every $x$, the amount of answers that are below $x$

Comment: Upvoted for good and useful advice.